# how to count only 1bits in binary representation of number without loop

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Suppose I have two numbers(minimum and maximum) . `

> for example (0 and 9999999999)

maximum could be so huge. now I also have some other number. it could be between those minimum and maximum number. `Let's say 15`. now What I need to do is get all the multiples of `15(15,30,45 and so on, until it reaches the maximum number)`. and for each these numbers, I have to count how many 1 bits there are in their binary representations. `for example, 15 has 4(because it has only 4 1bits).`

The problem is, I need a loop in a loop to get the result. first loop is to get all multiples of that specific number(in our example it was 15) and then for each multiple, i need another loop to count only 1bits. My solution takes so much time. Here is how I do it.

```
unsigned long long int min = 0;
    unsigned long long int max = 99999999;
    unsigned long long int other_num = 15; 
    unsigned long long int count = 0;

    unsigned long long int other_num_helper = other_num;
    while(true){
        if(other_num_helper > max) break;
        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(int)*4;i++){
            int buff = other_num_helper & 1<<i;
            if(buff != 0) count++; //if bit is not 0 and is anything else, then it's 1bits.
        }

        other_num_helper+=other_num;

    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
```

Comment: If you're asking for help and tips on improving your code, I suggest you go to (codereview.stackexchange.com)[codereview.stackexchange.com]. Otherwise can you maker it clearer what your question is about?

Comment: http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/c-program-to-count-number-of-ones-in-unsigned-integer.php look for divide and conquer strategy algorithm. It counds the bits for unsigned integer. I need the same thing for unsigned long long.

Comment: You can always adapt the given solution to your needs. In this case you'll need to change the constants: for example `0x55555555`will become `0x5555555555555555` if your `long long` is 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the bit patterns for the numbers between 0 and `2^3`

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

What do you see?

Every bit is one 4 times.

If you generalize, you find that the numbers between 0 and `2^n` have `n*2^(n-1)` bits set in total.

I am sure you can extend this reasoning for arbitrary bounds.

Comment: but i still need the first while loop right? is it possible not to use any loop?

Comment: @ntshetty yes, for example with n=5 you are considering the numbers between 0 and 32=2^5

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it for a 32 bit number.

```
std::uint16_t bitcount(
    std::uint32_t n
)
{
    register std::uint16_t reg;
    reg = n - ((n >> 1) & 033333333333)
            - ((n >> 2) & 011111111111);
    return ((reg + (reg >> 3)) & 030707070707) % 63;
}
```

And the supporting comments from the program:

Consider a 3 bit number as being 4a + 2b + c. If we shift it right 1 bit, we have 2a + b. Subtracting this from the original gives 2a + b + c. If we right-shift the original 3-bit number by two bits, we get a, and so with another subtraction we have a + b + c, which is the number of bits in the original number.

The first assignment statement in the routine computes 'reg'. Each digit in the octal representation is simply the number of 1’s in the corresponding three bit positions in 'n'.

The last return statement sums these octal digits to produce the final answer. The key idea is to add adjacent pairs of octal digits together and then compute the remainder modulus 63.

This is accomplished by right-shifting 'reg' by three bits, adding it to 'reg' itself and ANDing with a suitable mask. This yields a number in which groups of six adjacent bits (starting from the LSB) contain the number of 1’s among those six positions in n. This number modulo 63 yields the final answer. For 64-bit numbers, we would have to add triples of octal digits and use modulus 1023.